# Need to pass class object to ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

So I am working on API and using Ninject for DI & IoC. I know how the basic code works using Ninject but in the constructor of one of the classes an object of Logger is being sent. Rather than send it in constructor design item I would like to pass it in `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file.

```
public GAMonthlyAPIController() : this(new GAMonthlySQLReader(new NullLogger()))
```

This is the constructor.

```
kernel.Bind<IGAMonthlyReader>().To<GAMonthlySQLReader>();
```

This is the entry in `NinjectWebCommon.cs` I would like to bind it in `NinjectWebCommon.cs` rather than default value. How would I pass that? I don't even know what to search for, so I could find answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most practical way to apply the dependency injection pattern is to use constructor injection. This means that the classes `GaMonthlyAPIController` depend on should be passed in through the constructor, rather than hard-coded inside of the controller.

```
public class GAMonthlyAPIController
{
    private readonly IGAMonthlySQLReader gaMonthlySqlReader;

    public GAMonthlyAPIController(IGAMonthlySQLReader gaMonthlySqlReader)
    {
        this.gaMonthlySqlReader = gaMontlySqlReader 
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(gaMontlySqlReader));
    }

    // implementation of controller...
}
```

This should be the **only constructor** for your controller class. The controller itself doesn't know anything about `GAMontlySqlReader` or any of its dependencies.

The same goes for `GAMonthlySQLReader` - it will allow any `ILogger` implementation to be injected through the constructor.

The idea is that it puts the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) of the application in charge of how the dependencies are composed together, meaning you can easily switch them around later without making any changes to the components that you are composing. So, Ninject would be used inside of your composition root to map types to their abstraction, and then will build **object graphs** of all of those dependencies composed together.

```
kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<MyLoggerClass>();
kernel.Bind<IGAMonthlyReader>().To<GAMonthlySQLReader>();
```

For each of the application services, you would allow Ninject to instantiate them (so it can supply the dependencies) rather than using the `new` keyword inside of your application (`new` can be used for DTOs and Models, though).

Comment: So the logger I use, is used in instantiating GAMonthlySQLReader class. Logger is used in that class (right now does nothing but will log whatever it has to). Thats why I wanted to pass it in. If I declare following line
    kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<MyLoggerClass>();
I wouldn't have to pass it in to public GAMonthlyAPIController(IGAMonthlySQLReader gaMonthlySqlReader) but just instantiate in the class? Hope that made sense

Comment: If you register the Ninject with MVC as in [dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48647466/), your controllers will be instantiated through Ninject. When the controller is instantiated, Ninject will handle instantiating and passing all of the dependencies (provided they are registered with Ninject using `Bind` or similar). It will resolve the entire *object graph* of the controller. Later on, if you decide you want to use a different logger, you just need to change the Ninject config and it will switch for the entire application.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add Ninject.Web.WebApi using nuget to your Web Api project. Then use Ninject for creating ApiControllers:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
```

And add the Bind() for GAMonthlyAPIController. No need to create a default constructor for your controller.

Have a look to this post:
http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/04/web-api-2-and-ninject-how-to-make-them-work-together/

Comment: Your link definitely helped because I was seeing an exception no default constructor found.